# how to grep full cdr using one pattern

Tags: linux

i am having one file named SDPCDR_delsdp5_3037_20141120-201636.ASN this file contain some cdr in this format:
SDPOUTPUTCDRCP6.SDPCallDataRecord.serviceFeeDeduction

```
{
    sdpID : "delsdp5a"
    cdrID : "444293"
    originNodeType : "sdp"
    date : "20141120"
    time : "201735"
    accountNumber : "9697356704"
    serviceFeeAmount : "27.638000"
    successCode : 'ok (1)'
    oldServiceClass : '7604'D
    currencyType : '0'D
    servFeeExpDateBefore : "20141019"
    servFeeExpDateAfter : "20141218"
    accountFlags : "10001111"
    balanceAfterDeduction : "29.362000"
    gmtDeviation : "+0530"
    accountGroupID : '0'D
    serviceFeeType : "SUK_150"
    debt : "0.000000"
}
```

i am greppping like

```
grep SUK_150 SDPCDR_delsdp5_3037_20141120-201636.ASN
    serviceFeeType : "SUK_150"
so only serviceFeetype type is coming thats k the result will come like that only
but my concern is if any command is there if i grep 
"grep SUK_150 SDPCDR_delsdp5_3037_20141120-201636.ASN"
then full cdr came
```

i want output like

```
coomand-grep SUK_150 SDPCDR_delsdp5_3037_20141120-201636.ASN
```

result

```
SDPOUTPUTCDRCP6.SDPCallDataRecord.serviceFeeDeduction
{
    sdpID : "delsdp5a"
    cdrID : "444293"
    originNodeType : "sdp"
    date : "20141120"
    time : "201735"
    accountNumber : "9697356704"
    serviceFeeAmount : "27.638000"
    successCode : 'ok (1)'
    oldServiceClass : '7604'D
    currencyType : '0'D
    servFeeExpDateBefore : "20141019"
    servFeeExpDateAfter : "20141218"
    accountFlags : "10001111"
    balanceAfterDeduction : "29.362000"
    gmtDeviation : "+0530"
    accountGroupID : '0'D
    serviceFeeType : "SUK_150"
    debt : "0.000000"
}
```

i want whole cdr if i grep SUK_150

please suggest.

Comment: grep command print the matching line but not the whole something like paragraph. It is better to see the manual page of grep.

Answer (score 1):

Considering if the format is fixed.

```
grep -A2 -B18 SUK_150 SDPCDR_delsdp5_3037_20141120-201636.ASN
```

grep -A : prints X lines afterthe pattern match.
grep -B : prints X lines before the pattern match